# Where can I file bug reports to BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex

I have found a definite bug in BibTeX and I want to file it. However, there is no homepage dedicated to the program nor does its maintainer, Oren Patashnik, seem to have a homepage or publicly stated his e-mail address somewhere.

So, is there any proper way to draw the developer’s attention to this bug?

For the purpose of this question, assume that I ensured that it is really a bug, it is really happening in BibTeX (and not in some style file) and that there is no public statement that the bug is known.

Comment: How about you start posting it here so people can verify that this *is* indeed an bug, not just a possibly known *feature*

Comment: @daleif: Because at least according to [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6001/28608), questions on bugs should be closed and hence not be asked in the first place, if I know that it is a bug. Also, there is little to ask about this bug.

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that BibTeX, as a system, comprises both the executable program itself *and* the bibliography style file that informs the executable program *how* various bibliographic entries should be formatted. Without you providing more details about the alleged bug, it's not possible to determine if the bug is within the executable program or in the style file.

Comment: The fact that questions about bugs should be closed does not entail that questions about possible bugs should not be asked. [And it is easy to be really sure something is a bug and yet be wrong about it. Moreover, there are different varieties of bug, some of which are, and are known to be, in the 'won't fix' category.]

Comment: Should we assume, for the purposes of this question, that the bug is in the executable or the style file? If the latter, which style file should we assume to contain it? Why are you reluctant to describe the bug? Doing so would potentially make your question useful to more users, possibly itself attract the attention of the relevant developer(s) and generally satisfy the curious.

Comment: If you insist on secrecy about the bug itself, why do you post a question to a site that treats all material as "creative commons"?

Comment: @Mico I suspect the question is meant to be general so doesn't depend on there even being a bug to report.

Comment: @cfr: At least [according to Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1773/28608) TeX.Se should not be used to draw attention to bugs. And as Joseph Wright correctly remarked, this is intended as a general question that does not depend on the bug in question.

Comment: I too I'm curious about the bug and so would like to see it. Beside this: You could try the texlive list. They can perhaps adapt the binary or know something about the author.

Comment: The relevant annotation in the last uploaded version of `bibtex.web` (March 2010) is “Version 0.99d was released in March 2010.  It made output lines breakable only at `white_space` (so that, for example, URLs would not be broken). Other known bugs (all minor) will be fixed in a subsequent release.”

Comment: @JosephWright But there is still the issue of what it is the bug in. It wasn't clear to me from the question that it was in the binary and not, say, a `.bst`.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Then I disagree. It shouldn't be used in lieau of reporting. But there are many cases in which it is useful to have a bug noted here and any workarounds which may be available.

Comment: @cfr The question currently says '[the bug is] in BibTeX (and not in some style file)' so that seems clear, but a bug in one of the core `.bst` files would also need to go to Oren.

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry. Missed that change to the question. In the original, it was not at all obvious nor was it obvious whether a core `.bst` was used or another one.

Comment: @cfr On the meta question, the point there is that this is not the right place for bug reports. That doesn't preclude asking *if* something is a bug or how to work around it, but we have in the past had questions that were cases that were definitely 'pure' bug reports.

Comment: @JosephWright I'm not disputing that at all. I'm disputing a broader interpretation which I think was not the intention of the meta question/answers, as I've understood them. That's why I used 'possible bugs' in my initial comment. But I do also think that it is extremely easy to think that you have found a bug, while nonetheless being incorrect. ['You' here does not mean you. I don't doubt it may be easy for you. But for us mere mortals...;).]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with various parts of the TeX tool chain, often the most sensible way to report a bug in BibTeX is to raise the issue on the [TeX Live mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live). There are a range of TeX experts on that list and importantly the TeX Live developers are often in a good position to contact binary authors or to make changes to the code (license-dependent). Moreover, before that happens it's likely one or more list readers will test the input which leads the bug and will likely give feedback on whether it is a real issue or something which is documented behaviour. [Notably, http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/README lists Karl Berry along with Oren Patashnik: Karl is one of the TeX Live team and is contactable.)

Another approach to reporting bugs in TeX material where contact details are not clear is to ask the [CTAN](http://ctan.org) team if they can pass on a message. They hold a list of e-mail addresses for uploaders, and while they cannot give out that data they can pass messages on. They may have contact details for BibTeX.