# italic font in lmodern-lighttt

Tags: fonts, listings

In a search for a good monospaced font for my code listings I found the lmodern fonts. I really like the `lighttt` variant of those. The difference between normal and bold version is clearly visible with the `ttfamily`.

Recently however I discovered I also need italic version of those. Unfortunately the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Abc {\ttfamily abc {\bfseries abc} {\itshape abc}}
\end{document}
```

throws an error:

```
! No declaration for shape OT1/lmtt/l/sl
```

Is there a way to enable italic in this font?

---

With a bit of experimentation I soon discovered, that while italic is not available, it is possible to use the slanted font. `\slshape` works with lmodern-lighttt-ttfamily well enough.

However, while in the above MWE I use the `\itshape` explicitly and can be easily exchanged with `\slshape`, in my real scenario it is not always the case.

- I use listings package which automatically uses italic font in certain scenarios (e.g. comments in code)
- Sometimes I put short pieces of code in a caption, which - as a whole - is italic (and shouldn't use slanted)

A quick hack: `\renewcommand{\itshape}{\slshape}` is not reasonable in longer run either as it changes *all* italic fonts to slanted, while my concern is only in the monospaced case - when typing source code.

Maybe there is a way to treat `\itshape` as `\slshape` only in the context of monospaced font?

Comment: if you can extend your example to include some particular situations where `\slshape` may or should not be used (e.g. with the `listings` package and in captions), it will be easier to come up with a workaround.  i know it's been done, but the approach has to be quite environment-specific.

Comment: I hope there is a solution that would be environment independent - e.g. defining globally `ttfamily+itshape` as `ttfamily+slshape`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update 2023

in a current texlive 2023 the bug has been corrected and this works without error (and gives a slanted typewriter)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Abc {\ttfamily abc  \itshape abc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### 0ld answer

That's a bug in the fd-files (`OT1lmtt.fd` and `T1lmtt.fd`): In the "lighttt" section they substitute the `lmtt/m/it` to `lmtt/l/sl` instead of `lmtt/m/sl`. You should report it.

You can get around it with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
\ttfamily
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{it}
     {<->sub*lmtt/m/sl}{}

\begin{document}
Abc {\ttfamily abc  \itshape abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solves my issue! In my real document I use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. In the line `DeclareFontShape` I used `{T1}` instead of `{OT1}` and it works fine.

Comment: I am reluctant to report the bug to the creators though, since I know very little about inner workings of the package and the font system. The `\DeclareFontShape...` line is "black magic" for me.

Comment: The authors won't bite you. You can sent them the link to your question and my answer and if they really don't know what I mean they can contact me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I reported this bug on January 11, 2011 (sic) in a mail with destinatories `Boguslaw Jackowski` and `Karl Berry` (as I was using TeXLive and wasn't aware of how TeX/LaTeX world was structured). In my patched version I also use `ssub` rather than `sub`. There is also a problem with `sb/it->m/sl` which should be `sb/it->sb/sl` signaled in my patched version.

Comment: My mail started with: Dear Mr Jackowski [snip] it seems that some font shape substitutions are afflicted by typos in the files il2lmvtt.fd, l7xlmvtt.fd, ly1lmvtt.fd, ot1lmvtt.fd, ot4lmvtt.fd, qxlmvtt.fd, t1lmvtt.fd, t5lmvtt.fd, ts1lmvtt.fd  ... [snip]

Comment: @jfbu: You could try to contact the CTAN team, or write to the texlive list. See Joseph's advice here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232735/2388

Comment: I've tried compiling this snippet but the font looks still slanted and not italic. It seems like the substitution is no longer working.

Comment: @Atcold that it looks slanted is normal, that is a typewriter font. (the patch is no longer needed in a current texlive).

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense to me. The default LaTeX monospace font has an italic variant as well, and it's not simply a ‘slanted’ fake italic.

Comment: I created [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685994/33287) where I can illustrate more clearly what's going on. Apologies for the succinctness of my previous message.