# Typewriter non-bold font with italic support and Greek letters

Tags: bold, italic, typewriter

I'm explaining some code that uses Greek characters, **bold**, *italic*, and accents.

The default font does not differentiate between **bold** and non-bold.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ttgreek}{LGR}{cmtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ttdelta}{\mathord}{ttgreek}{`d}
\begin{document}

\texttt{Writing some \textbf{bold}, \emph{italic},
Greek $\ttdelta$, and accents $\mathtt{\tilde{y}}$.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}` lets me distinguish between **bold** and non-bold, but the *italic* becomes slanted and the Greek keeps being bold.

[image]

What I want is:

- differentiate between **bold** and non-bold,
- have a working *italic*,
- use non-bold Greek letters like δ, and
- keep using accents.

## Use case

I have these requirements for the code snippets in my book.
Below, you can see the lack of *italic* for the comments.
The alternative was a lack of **bold** for the Python keywords.

[image]

```
Then, we compute \(\Fi\) and \(\vzchk\) with the following algorithm.
\begin{CodeEnv}
\pydef dict_inference(net, \m\ce, \m\cc):
  \m\vz0 = net.sample_latent()  \mc{# initial guess, all zeros}
  \m\vzchk = compute_\m\vzchk(\m\ce, \m\vz0)
  t2 = net.top2(\m\vzchk)          \mc{# get top-2 (t2) units}
  \m\vzchk2 = compute_\m\vzchk(\m\cc, t2)
  \m\cF = \m\ce(\m\vzchk2)                 \mc{# compute the free energy}
  \pyreturn \m\cF, net.pad(\m\vzchk2)
\end{CodeEnv}
\begin{compactenum}
  \item compute \(\vzchk\) by minimising \(\ce(\vz)\),
  \item zero all but the two most active components of the code \(\vzchk\),
  \item minimise \(\cc(\vz)\) wrt these two components,
  \item evaluate and return \(\Fiy = \ce(\vzchk)\) and \(\vzchk\).
\end{compactenum}
```

Comment: do you need math accents?  `$\mathtt{\tilde{y}}$` not `\texttt{\~{y}}` ?

Comment: I have a macro for my vector-y-tilde `\vytld` which is used in the math environment and I make it monospaced by encapsulating it in a `\mathtt{}` macro. My major issue is with a working monospace font that supports italic, bold, and non-bold Greek characters.

Comment: I would guess there is a very limited choice of monospace italic (not slanted) fonts

Comment: are your delta and the character with accent really math, or are you only using math because it looks right and in reality you have text characters?

Comment: My equations use Greek and accents. My Python code reflects such use. The LaTeX reproduces and describes the code. Let me integrate a use case in the question, so you better understand what I'm doing. The math in the code is the same math (same macros) I use in my formulas wrapped in a `\mathtt{}`. So… I'm not sure I've answered your question. Please, let me know.

Comment: For the Greek, I'd rather use Unicode / text characters indeed. I'm not sure if this would work with PdfLaTeX, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`xfakebold`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xfakebold) package.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ttgreek}{LGR}{cmtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ttdelta}{\mathord}{ttgreek}{`d}
\usepackage[bold=0.3]{xfakebold}

\begin{document}
    \texttt{Writing some \setBold\textbf{bold}\unsetBold, \textit{italic}, Greek $\ttdelta$, and accents \(\mathtt{\tilde{y}}\).}
\end{document}
```

[image: bold textttt]

Comment: Someone knowledgeable in macros can change the textbf command in the texttt environment to automatically insert setBold and unsetBold commands automatically, or define a new command which does this.

Comment: Honestly, this looks very good and I'd be handling the formatting part with macros, so the `\[un]setBold` is not even a problem. I just wonder why the overall text looks thinner than the one I showed in my screenshot. Maybe I'm just hallucinating this…

Comment: @Atcold Are you on mac os? If yes, then that might be the reason. The displayed text generally looks thicker on mac os compared to Linux or Windows (I am on Linux, Manjaro KDE). See my comment here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460517/how-to-compile-thicker-otf-version-of-latin-modern-fonts/554249#comment1646345_554249

Comment: \*I am\* on Mac. Though, I used TeXShop for the screenshots. I am using your `xfakebold` suggestion with the `lmtt` font suggested by David. I don't know what answer I'm supposed to accept now :/

Answer (score 4):

latin modern typewriter seems to have the forms you need

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ttgreek}{LGR}{lmtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ttdelta}{\mathord}{ttgreek}{`d}
\begin{document}

\texttt{Writing some \textbf{bold} and \emph{italic} and
Greek $\ttdelta$ and accents $\mathtt{\tilde{y}}$.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the bold isn't that much different from the regular weight.  This was also true of the original `cmtt` font.  For a project where being able to distinguish between the two was essential, at AMS we defined a real lightface version.  But that was in Metafont days, and the font is long gone.

Comment: Thanks, David. How did you find this font? Meaning, how would a LaTeX user go around finding such a font, given its desired features (as listed in my post)?

Comment: @Atcold er... does "I have been using latex for 35 years and knew the font was there" count as an answer?

Comment: Hahaha! What I meant is, where would one look for understanding what `cmtt` is and where to find the `lmtt` variant? `texdoc cmtt` returns a rather old package documentation that has no font table.

Comment: Also, I'm using `lmtt` you suggested (which look lighter than `cmtt`) with `xfakebold` Apoorv pointed out (to increase the bold contrast). I'm not sure which answer I should accept now.

Comment: give points to newcomers, I can manage without a green tick...

Comment: Very kind of you. Thanks a bunch for helping! You'll definitely make it to the acknowledgement section of the book! <3

Answer (score 2):

if you are not bound to pdflatex you could use the lualatex and the newcomputer modern fonts. (The bold is not very bold, but you can embolden it, see the bold italic):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{NewCMMono10-Regular.otf}%
 [%
  ItalicFont=NewCMMono10-BookItalic.otf,%
  BoldFont=NewCMMono10-Bold.otf,%
  %BoldFeatures={FakeBold=2}, %bolder?
  BoldItalicFont=NewCMMono10-BoldOblique.otf,%
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=2}
 ]

\begin{document}

\texttt{Writing some \textbf{bold} and \emph{italic}  and \emph{\textbf{bold italic}}\\
 and Greek δ and accent ỹ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike. There is very little difference between bold and non-bold. I think FakeBold may be a good direction, though. And, as Apoorv Potnis points out, this can be achieved with a package that does not require LuaLaTeX.